# RecycleView not showing the result

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recycleView and I set to it an adapter but I don't know why it is showing nothing. I think that I am doing the same thing I made everytime I have to use it... Here is the code:

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/iron">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/appointment_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity:

Here I use a presenter that gives me a list. I debug it and it works.

```
public class AppointmentDateSelectionView extends NotificationActivity implements MVP.View {

    RecyclerView dayAppointments;


    AppointmentDateSelectionPresenter presenter;

    private ListAdapter adapter;
    List<ResponseAppointmentHours> availableHours;
    private int idDoctor;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment_date_selection);
        BaseManager<String> managerToken = new TokenManager(getApplicationContext());
        dayAppointments = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.appointment_list);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        idDoctor = i.getIntExtra(Params.INTENT.ID_DOCTOR, 0);
        presenter = new AppointmentDateSelectionPresenter(managerToken, idDoctor);
        presenter.onViewCreated(this);
        presenter.initialize();
        dayAppointments.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    }

@Override
    public void setDoctorAppointmentList(List<ResponseAppointmentHours> hoursList) {
        availableHours = hoursList;
        adapter = new ListAdapter(availableHours);
        dayAppointments.setAdapter(adapter);
        dayAppointments.setItemAnimator(new CustomDefaultItemAnimator());
        dayAppointments.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private final OnDeleteClickListener listener1;

    private static List<ResponseAvailableHours> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.availability_from)
        TextView availabilityText;

        @BindView(R.id.delete)
        ImageView delete;


        ItemViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        }

        public void bind(final ResponseAvailableHours item, final OnDeleteClickListener listener) {
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    list.remove(item);
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    ListAdapter(OnDeleteClickListener listener1, List<ResponseAvailableHours> data) {
        this.listener1 = listener1;
        list = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.avaliability_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ResponseAvailableHours hour = list.get(position);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date endDate = formatter.parse(hour.getTimeEnd());
            Date iniTime = formatter.parse(hour.getTimeIni());
            String available = "Cada " + WeekDays.getDays(hour.getWeekday()) + " de " + newFormat.format(iniTime) + "h a " + newFormat.format(endDate) + "h";
            holder.availabilityText.setText(available);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.bind(hour, listener1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

In the activity when it passes from `adapter = new ListAdapter(availableHours);` The ListAdapter method is fired correctly but nothing else is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, it seems that after initializing your recycler view (dayAppointments), you have forgot to add the layout manager.

Try adding following code, hope it may helps

```
dayAppointments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));// since you have activity
```

If you want to use it in fragment,

```
dayAppointments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add LayoutManager

```
dayAppointments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

after list initialization for horizontal. You also can make it vertical or use GridLayoutManager